# Cannot find the 'property name' in angular 7 (Compile time error)

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular2-services

I'm trying to integrate my backend api with frontend.I'm getting the following error.
Cannot find name 'cus_id'.
Cannot find name 'username'.
Cannot find name 'fullname'.etc

expect 'location and status ' all other property name is error.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPSHy.png)

```
Customer.component.ts
```

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cs: CustomerService, private ps: ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.showSuccess = false;
    this.getProductList();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.customer_addForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [''],
      cus_id: [''],
      email: [''],
      fullname: [''],
      customer_currency: [''],
      mobile_primary: [''],
      website: [''],
      country: [''],
      location: [''],
      city: [''],
      postal_code: [''],
      status: [''],
      productList: ['']
    });
  }

  submitcustomeraddForm() {
    this.showSuccess = false;
    this.allProducts = _.uniq[this.allProducts];

   

    this.cs.addCustomer(username,
      cus_id, email,
      fullname,  customer_currency,
      mobile_primary,  website,
      country,  location,
       city,
      postal_code,
      status,
      productList);
  }
```

Customer.service.ts

```js
export class CustomerService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:3000/customer';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 addCustomer(username,
  cus_id, email,
  fullname,  customer_currency,
  mobile_primary,  website,
  country,  location,
   city,
  postal_code,
  status,
  productList) {

  const obj = {
    username: username,
    cus_id: cus_id,
    email: email,
    fullname: fullname,
    customer_currency:  customer_currency,
    mobile_primary:  mobile_primary,
    website:  website,
    country:  country,
    location:  location,
    city:  city,
    postal_code:  postal_code,
    status:  status,
    productList: productList
  };
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/add`, obj).subscribe(res => console.log('done'));
  }
```

I've searched for solution in web , but i didn't found one.i've no idea why it is showing not found.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an IDE that is capable to show you TypeScript errors. I can recommend IntelliJ and VS Code.

[image]

To get a forms value use e.g. this syntax:

```
this.customer_addForm.value.cus_id
```

Edit 1: [res.status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plM1L.png)

Comment: At first i tried using `this.customer_addForm.value.cus_id` ,it didn't worked

Comment: So you should do see red. Red means, won't work.

In your `  submitcustomeraddForm()` make a console log of  `this.customer_addForm.value`. What do you get?

Comment: getting another error **Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.**

Comment: ` status: this.customer_addForm.value.status,
      productList: this.allProducts

    };

    this.cs.addCustomer(data)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      if (res.**status**) {
        this.showSuccess = true ;
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }

    });
`